# Encoding gets lost while exporting database

Tags: mysql, sql, encoding, utf-8, export

I'm facing a weird issue with file encoding while exporting the database.

To put it simply,

Exporting database DON'T preserve Unicode characters. 
Exporting individual tables DO preserve Unicode characters.

The dump sql file that I get when I export it as a whole database even has the default charset set to utf8 such as below.

CREATE TABLE `content_field_tamil` ( `vid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `nid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', `field_tamil_value` longtext, `field_tamil_format` int(10) unsigned default NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`vid`), KEY `nid` (`nid`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Sample field value of field 'field_tamil_value':

‡Æâ‡Æ±‡Øç‡Æ±‡Ææ‡Æ∞ - This is what I get when I export it as a whole database in .sql file. This is wrongly encoded. 
உற்றார் - This is what I get when I export individual tables. And this is correct.

I don't understand why it's encoding differently when I export it as a whole database. And, it does the same in my localhost test database. Any help is really appreciated guys.

Comment: I don't know about MySQL in enough detail to give a complete answer, but I'd suggest investigating use of `CHARACTER SET` and/or `COLLATE` when specifying your datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've tried this, but is the charset on the *database* set to utf8?  E.g. not just the tables.

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]

ALTER DATABASE db_name
    [[DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [[DEFAULT] COLLATE collation_name]
```